# Android webview not resize on device

Tags: android, webview, resize

Im working on my first android app. Im having a very strange problem with WebView Component of Android. My website have responsive design. The problem is it resize fine on Emulator but when i run on my device webview show normal design, not responsive. Any idea? this is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView myWebView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); 
 myWebView.loadUrl("http://apelarse.com.ar");

 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
}

private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
}

    } 

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  } 
}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I copy the code from this site: http://samadmalik.com/converting-website-android-app/

Comment: Rather show your xml layout definition please.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />  

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it should work (even if webview parameters at first glance look a bit strange).

Comment: And please also note I use LinearLayout. If possible use it too as usually you have less problems with it comparing to RelativeLayout.

Comment: With the parameters as above (in my example)?

Comment: So I really don't why it doesn't work. I copied part of my own code (slightly simplyfing by removing elements which are not necessary). Perhaps it's somehow related with minsdk. In my project it's set to 14.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add this:

`webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)`